# How to convert horizontal coordinates using NOVAS?

Tags: fundamental-astronomy, coordinate, software

I'm using NOVAS 3.1. I know that I can convert equatorial coordinates to horizontal coordinates using the `equ2hor` function.

Is it possible to make NOVAS do the inverse transformation: from horizontal to equatorial? There is no `hor2equ`, but maybe some other function implements this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the reply I got from the US Naval Observatory itself:

> No, we do not have that transformation in NOVAS.  Generally, altitude and azimuth are not determined to very high accuracy, so using them to obtain RA and Dec, which are much more precisely defined and measured, does not make a lot of sense.